# How to access docker service with docker private ip and port from different host in aws without port forwarding or using docker host ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, firewall, iptables

I have the following setup, where both host are in same VPC.

Host1:

```
 public ip : 53.X.X.X 
 private ip : 172.X.X.X 
 docker ip : 173.16.42.1 (bridge ip)
```

Host2:

```
 public ip : 53.X.X.X 
 private ip : 172.X.X.X
```

Now, when I launch container from host1, let's say tomcat, how can I access this server with private and port from Host2?

I wanted like this from host2 173.16.42.2:8080.Added host1 nameserver in host2.

Basically, I wanted this use case because I am using consul for service discovery, and in consul service are registered as 173.16.42.2:8080. But when I do nslookup tomcat.service.consul I am able to resolve the service ip and port. But when I do a telnet or curl for this ip"port it times out. Allowed all traffic and iptables rule between hosts.

I am able to achive above usecase with port forwarding and accessing service using host ip.But i need the above approach 173.16.42.2:8080 from host2

So any suggesation would be helpful

Comment: Could you access that service from a docker container on host2? Because with network overlay, that second container would see the first container hostname, and would be able to access it directly.

Comment: Thanks VonC for quick reply, no i have not tested the container to container in different host. I wanted somthing like host2 to host1 container access with docker private ip.

Comment: As per my knowledge docker creates a virtual interface, through which host can access container and vice-versa. If we able to bind this virtual interface to host2 we might able to ping accross the host, not sure this is correct approach.But even if this is correct how to do that